# Fill GridView based on DropDownList.SelectedValue and Button Click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

struggling since morning. the scenario is as follow:
I have a ASP.NET web page having

- two dropdownlist
- two buttons
- One GridView
  Wants to fill gridview based on dropdownlist selected value
  here is the .aspx code

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/ADMIN.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="EditSTUdetail.aspx.vb" Inherits="Admin_EditSTUdetail" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1
        {
            height: 42px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <div align="center">
        <fieldset>
            <legend style="font-size: 16px;">SEARCH / EDIT / DELETE STUDENT RECORDS
            </legend>
            <div style="overflow: auto">
                <div>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" CssClass="lblresponse" />
                    <table style="margin: 3px auto 1px auto; height: 72px;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;" class="auto-style2">Select Session/सत्र का चयन करें :
                            </td>
                            <td class="auto-style3">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSession" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Width="236px" Height="28px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Session--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="ddlSession" ForeColor="#990000"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align: right;" class="auto-style1">Select Course /कक्षा का चयन करें :
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourse" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="236px" Height="28px">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="--Select Course--" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="ddlCourse" ForeColor="#990000"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="auto-style1"></td>
                            <td class="auto-style1">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="SEARCH" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Height="34px" Width="77px" /></td>
                            <td colspan="2" class="auto-style1">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                           <asp:Button ID="btnRefresh" runat="server" Text="REFRESH" CssClass="button" OnClick="btnRefresh_Click" Height="34px" Width="77px" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <asp:GridView ID="GVdata" runat="server" Width="674px" CaptionAlign="Top"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="100px" BackColor="White"
                BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"
                CellSpacing="2" GridLines="Vertical"
                EmptyDataText="There Are No Record Found" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvManageOrders_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowDeleting="gvManageOrders_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="gvManageOrders_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="gvManageOrders_RowUpdating">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sr. No." ItemStyle-Width="20">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField HeaderText="Edit/Remove" ShowDeleteButton="True"
                        ShowEditButton="True" DeleteText="Remove" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student ID" Visible="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="studentID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("studentID")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Student Name" Visible="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Sname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Sname")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Father's Name" Visible="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="Fname" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fname")%>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#eeeeee" BorderColor="Black"
                    BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="#851010"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#851010" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#851010" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
            </asp:GridView>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and here is my vb code:

```
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Data
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Partial Public Class Admin_EditSTUdetail
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private myds As DataSet
    Protected Sub LoadSession()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cmsDB").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim com As New SqlCommand("select sessionID, session from tblcategories ORDER by session DESC", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        ddlSession.DataTextField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("session").ToString()
        ' text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        ddlSession.DataValueField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("sessionID").ToString()
        ' to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlSession.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        'assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlSession.DataBind()
        ddlSession.SelectedIndex = -1
        'binding dropdownlist
    End Sub
    Protected Sub LoadCourse()
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cmsDB").ConnectionString)
        con.Open()
        Dim com As New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT course AS mycolumn FROM " _
                                     & " tblsubjects where course is not null and " _
                                     & "not course = '' order by mycolumn", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(com)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        da.Fill(ds)
        ddlCourse.DataTextField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("mycolumn").ToString()
        ' text field name of table dispalyed in dropdown
        ddlCourse.DataValueField = ds.Tables(0).Columns("mycolumn").ToString()
        ' to retrive specific  textfield name 
        ddlCourse.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        'assigning datasource to the dropdownlist
        ddlCourse.DataBind()
        ddlCourse.SelectedIndex = -1
        'binding dropdownlist
    End Sub


    Protected Sub fillgrid()
        Dim cn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("cmsDB").ConnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT StudentID,session,course,Sname,Fname FROM [tblstudetail]  WHERE " _
                              & " [session] = '" + ddlSession.SelectedValue.ToString() + "' AND " _
                              & " [course] = '" + ddlCourse.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'", cn)

        cn.Open()
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        myds = New DataSet()
        da.Fill(myds)
        GVdata.DataSource = myds
        GVdata.DataBind()

    End Sub

    Private Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            LoadSession()
            LoadCourse()
            fillgrid()
        End If

    End Sub


    Protected Sub gvManageOrders_RowCancelingEdit(sender As Object, e As GridViewCancelEditEventArgs)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvManageOrders_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvManageOrders_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As GridViewEditEventArgs)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Protected Sub gvManageOrders_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
           fillgrid()
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub btnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRefresh.Click
        GVdata.DataSource = Nothing
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it is not returning what i request.
Kindly HELP me out this....

Comment: where is dropdown changed method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease remove these lines ,

`ddlSession.SelectedIndex = -1
     ddlCourse.SelectedIndex = -1`
from the end of the `LoadCourse` and `LoadSession` methods. These are resetting the dropdown values and causing issue.

The flow is messed up in your code. You are calling loadsession , loadcourses and fillgrid serially from the page load method. Think about it. When the code in fillgrid executes there is no selected value in the drop downs. Obviously no data is found and so the gridview is not visible.

The better way to handle is introduce two new methods like this,

```
 Protected Sub ddlCourses_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlSession.SelectedIndexChanged
```

and
`Protected Sub ddlAC3_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlCourse.SelectedIndexChanged`

Inside these methods send out a call to fillgrid. 
Also inside the fillgrid method first validate there is some value in both the ddlCourse and ddlSession dropdowns , then send out the database command.

Comment: i did it but no success..("-")

Comment: Ok. Run the application and attach a breakpoint at the third line of the fillgrid() method. When the execution stops here. Check the values of the ddlSession.SelectedValue.ToString() and ddlCourse.SelectedValue.ToString() in the immediate window.

Comment: Can you hard code some valid values in the query string for which there will be some data in the ```myds``` and check if the gridview still does not show up ?

Comment: when i remove where clause then its fill gridview with all data available in the table. please help...

Comment: Yeah so the issue is because there is no data in the myds the gridview is not visible. In your code you have to make sure that there is some data in the ddlSession and ddlCourse dropdowns.

Comment: so how to fill ddlsession

Comment: see i have updated the answer. Basically you need to add two handlers for the two dropdowns and call to fillgrid from there.

Comment: Change the selection on the course and session dropdown and check please

Comment: NO, not a single DDL value works at brkpoint its showing last to digit after -

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you are using now ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
ddlSession.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

become

```
ddlSession.SelectedValue
```

Then in Protected Sub btnSearch_Click remove

```
 If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
```

Then

```
ddlCourse.SelectedIndex = -1
```

become

```
ddlCourse.ClearSelection();
```

Finally, are you sure there aren't NULL value in the database?

Comment: YES there are NULL. I manage it with ddlSession.SelectedItems.Value. Its working but i an not confident. Also is their any idea to search between all column using Textbox.text.

Comment: Try exclude all NULL session/sessionId.
You can use also jquery.ui autocomplete